# Characterization of stationary points on the plane.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $x \in U$ a recurring point for a class $C^{1}$ vector field $F:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined in an open $V$ of the plane. Show that either $x$ is a stationary point or $x$ is a periodic regular point.

Comment: I tried to use Jordan's Closes Curve theorem nas Poincaré's Recurrence theorem, but I was not successful.